# iOS 7 themes - why is mine white?

Tags: ios

I thought with iOS 7 the theme was supposed to be based on the colour of the device. If this is the case why does my black iPad have the white theme.

If this is not the case how do I change it to a black theme?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by theme? The only difference between white and black colored devices in iOS 7 was the boot up screen, that is in you case when the iPad boots there should be a black screen with a white Apple Logo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only the iPhone 5C has any *theme* support, in that they contain custom wallpaper to match the colour of the device which is selected as a default when first using the device.  This themeing does not extend into apps, and is simply a pre-chosen wallpaper.  It has no relevance for any other phone model, or iPad.

Answer (score 3):

There aren't any themes in iOS 7. Everything you see in apps such as Mail, Music and Calendars is white, regardless of the colour of your device. The only thing that is different is the boot-up screen.

You may notice that the keyboard may change colour depending on where you're at. For example, in Messages it is white and when searching for something in Spotlight is is black.

Comment: The headline a the top of the screen may switch from white to black, depending on what the background is.